# Значение слова "плечо"

Tags: семантика

Плечо, как известно, часть руки от плечевого сустава (коим рука "крепится" к телу) до локтевого.
Кто-нибудь может объяснить, почему некоторые оригиналы голову имеют ***на плечах***, а отдельные граждане там же носят ещё и погоны? Там, под погонами - от плечевого сустава до шеи - не то что плеча, вообще кости нету. Одна кожа, натянутая на трепециевидные мышцы.

Comment: Спросите у портных, что они называют длиной плеча, когда снимают мерки. Вот [здесь](http://www.sewing-master.ru/merki.html) и бедра и плечи.  

Я в молодости пыталась шить, так что мне это все близко и понятно.  

Кстати, "плечо" в Вашем понимании называется там "верхняя часть руки". И так думают многие, не учившиеся в медицинских вузах!

Comment: Ну, видимо не только. Голова на плечах - не новое выражение.  

Жаль, что здесь нельзя провести опрос. Если сказать человеку: "у тебя на плече пчела" - куда он посмотрит? 

Сужу по себе: я _знаю_, что верхняя часть руки называется плечом, но я так не думаю. Это знание - на периферии сознания. И пчелу я буду искать поверх ключицы.

Comment: И я. Однозначно!

Comment: Оплечье и подоплека (одежда) происхождение имеют очень древнее, в то время как никакой части руки они зачастую не покрывают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю как биолог. Плечо — часть руки то шеи до локтя, а от локтя до запястья — это предплечье.

Comment: А руки у нас из шеи растут?  
В этом-то вся проблема...

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, если я Вам, как биологу, скажу: "У Вас на левом плече пятно краски", Вы на какую часть тела посмотрите?  Не все же мы биологи и медики! Так что Ваше определение - это уже, в некотором смысле, научный жаргон.

Comment: Ответы биологов имеют косвенное отношение к вопросу, как и их утверждение, что арбуз — это ягода, например, а плоды клубники — нет. Биология не устанавливает значения слов, а берёт подходящие для своей терминологии.

Answer (score 8):

У Даля: плечо - часть тела от шеи до локтя.У Ушакова и потом у Ожегова значение уж**е** **у**же- часть тела от шеи до руки: нести что-нибудь  на плече. (Ленин все-таки бревно нес не на верхней части руки! )А  значение "верхняя часть руки" дается с пометой - в анатомии.

Comment: Тот же вопрос. Руки растут не из шеи. Росли бы из шеи - проблем бы не было.

Answer (score 6):

Я думаю, что слова 'широкоплечий', 'подплечники', выражения 'косая сажень в плечах', 'плюнуть через левое плечо' образованы именно от первого значения слова, приведённого в  ответе выше.

Comment: Косая сажень - точно нет. 
Обычная сажень - это расстояние между пальцами вытянутых в стороны рук. Т.е. - в плечах. Косая - расстояние от пальцев руки до пальцев противоположной ноги. А выражение приравнивает это максимальное расстояние плечевому. Тут все понятно.  
Остальное не буду комментировать, хотя плюнуть через то самое место (где погоны) довольно-таки затруднительно.

Comment: А через верхнюю часть руки, на мой взгляд, еще сложнее. Наклоняться придется. А когда плюют (например, чтобы "не сглазить"), то все-таки через "часть туловища от шеи до руки"

Comment: Ясно, что первоначальный смысл слова "плечо" был связан с лопаткой, с верхней частью туловища слева и справа от головы. И уж потом перешел на медицинское название части руки.  
В этом нет ничего особенного. Например, stomach -  желудок, а стоматолог занимается ротовой полостью.

Answer (score 4):

Очень похоже, что наших предков особо не интересовала разница между областью от шеи и до конца туловища и рукой от локтя до шеи. Всё это они называли *плечом*. Если задуматься, то в этом нет ничего удивительного. При использовании плеч для переноски чего либо, как правило, используется всё это пространство. Например, коромысло на плечах:

[image]

Тоже самое касается переноски на плечах котомки, мешка или ружья (без ремня), которые то "сползают" на плечо медицинское, то снова на плече бытовом.

При производстве одежды зона от шеи до руки, тоже не имела значения. Так как холсты ткались у́же туловища, то к прямоугольнику холста пришивались рукава и боковины. Подробнее о производстве рубахи с фотографией можно посмотреть по [ссылке](http://via-midgard.info/news/article/13537-muzhskaya-narodnaya-odezhda.html), здесь же приведу просто схему швов.

[image]

При разделке животного, опять-таки передние конечности отрезают вместе с лопаткой,  т.е. всё плечо в широком понимании. [Разделка свиньи](http://www.idilbay.ru/razd.php)

В дальнейшем, при изменении кроя одежды, и способов переноски (ремень, лямки) плечо в ряде специальностей приобрело более узкое значение (от шеи до руки), но при этом верхняя часть руки потеряла имя. В то время как в других областях (прежде всего медицина) наоборот от локтя до туловища плечо, а между шеей и рукой ничего.

Answer (score 3):

“плечо” в словаре Ефремовой
1)

> а) Часть туловища от шеи до руки.
> б) Часть одежды, покрывающая туловище от шеи до руки.

2) Верхняя часть руки (или передней конечности животного) до локтевого сустава.
3)

> а) Часть предмета, расположенная под углом к остальной его части.
> б) Склон горы, скалы и т.п.

4) Часть рычага от точки опоры до точки приложения силы.

Каждый выбирает, какое хочет.

Думаю, все же расширение смысла идет от лопатки (1а) к руке (2). Тем болtе, что в Фасмере:

> Если считать исключительно русск. формы на -к- вторичными, то можно было бы исходить из древнего *рlеti̯о-. В таком случае налицо было бы родство с ирл. leithe ж. "лопатка" (*pleti̯ā); сюда же далее лит. plė̃sti, plečiù "расстилать, растягивать, расширять", splė̃sti, splėčiù – то же, греч. ὠμοπλάτη "лопатка", πλατύς "плоский, широкий", лит. platùs "широкий" (см. также плесна́);

Плечо как часть руки все же больше медицинский термин.

Comment: Ефремова явно оригинальничает. По "толувище и шею" - это многовато будет.  
Ну хорошо, а выражение "руки на бедра" вы когда-нибудь слышали? Бедро - это тоже (по Ефремовой) мягкое место сбоку от пупка?

Comment: Не знаю, как у Ефремовой, у меня - да. Для меня "плечо" как верхняя часть руки и "бедро" как верхняя часть ноги - понятные, но "неродные" термины. Именно термины в медицинском смысле.  

И вообще Ваш вопрос не очень понятен, слишком эмоционально. Вы считаете, что так говорить неправильно? Или задумываетесь, какой смысл первичен? Оба они явно существуют.  

Или у Вас "душа не принимает" другие смыслы ;-))

Comment: В принципе я тоже так думал. Класса до третьего. В четвертом меня без особых трудов переубедили. Сегодня столкнулся как раз с таким предтавителем "неучившихся". Итогом стал этот вопрос.  
Медицина, кстати, тут ни при чем. Спросите механика, желзнодорожника или водилу-дальнобойщика, что твок плечо - он вам ответит, что это нечто длинное, одним концом шарнирно закреплённое... На железной дороге, например, плечо -  расстояние (в одну сторону), которое пробегает локомотив, отправляясь в рейс из родного депо. Примерно соответcnвует смене обслуживающей бригады. И только портные оригинальничают.

Comment: Не только портные. Думаю, что команда "На плечо" также отражает общепринятое (не анатомическое) понимание. [Здесь](http://stjag.ru/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=31387), правда, нет картинки, но слова "в выемку плеча" явно __не__ указывают на верхнюю часть руки. Там выемок нет.

Answer (score 1):

И водила-дальнобойщик, кстати, никогда Вам не ответит, что плечо - это "нечто длинное, одним концом шарнирно закреплённое". Он скажет, что плечо - это расстояние перегона (отсюда название проституток на трассе - плечевые).

Comment: А если подумать? 
Во-первых, не "расстояние перегона", а путь "дома" до пункта назначение. Во-вторых, это то же самое, что на ж/д, ну и самое главное. Закрепленный конец - это пункт А, гараж, куда он должен вернуться. Он всегда один. Пункты назначения - разные. Отсюда и полная аналогия с шарнирным закреплением. Ну или "плечом" анатомическим.  

Ну а проститутки - это уже кто о чем ))).

Comment: А тут не надо думать, так как "плечо" - это именно расстояние перегона, а не какой-то непонятный путь какого-то "дома" до какого-то пункта назначениЯ. Да и на ж/д такого термина "плечо" нет (есть тока термин "перегон"). 

А тема про "закрепленный конец" - это всё софистика чистой воды.


Мы такое не едим!

Comment: Думать всегда надо. Простите.   
Если вы попытаетесь сформулировать Вашу мысль так, чтобы было понятно, что именно вы говорите нового или чему возражаете в плане написанного, разговоры о том, что надо делать отпадут сами собой.   
По мне - так все это уже давно сказано, пережевано и обсосано.  

>Да и на ж/д такого термина "плечо" нет (есть тока термин "перегон").   
  
Есть, уважаемый. Вы не в курсе. И кстат, совсем не эквиваленгно перегону". Значение его я привел. Дальнейшее препирательство на эту тему считаю бессмысленным.

Comment: >Да и на ж/д такого термина "плечо" нет (есть тока термин "перегон").   
  
Есть, уважаемый. Вы не в курсе. И кстат, совсем не эквивалентно перегону". Значение его я привел. По секрету скажу, что длина плеча на российский ж.д установлена в 400 км. Примерно конечно. После этого производится смена локомотива или бригады. 
Дальнейшее препирательство на эту тему считаю бессмысленным.

Answer (score 0):

Как предположение,
слово плечо имеет отношение к устройству не анатомическому, а механическому. Так же как плечо у рычага, вращаясь вокруг позвоночника, мы получаем плечо.
У Даля:
плече ср. (в сложных словах также плёко; одноплёкий, подоплёка) рамо
Рама - как раз такое устройство, которое работает на изгиб и использует рычаги.

Answer (score 0):

***ПЛЕЧО:***
***В анатомии:***

- Плечевой пояс (пояс верхних
     конечностей) — совокупность костей,
     обеспечивающих опору и движение
     верхних конечностей.
- Плечо — часть верхней конечности,
     соответствующая плечевой кости.

***В физике:***

- Плечо — часть рычага от точки опоры
     до точки приложения силы.

***В экономике:***

- Кредитное плечо

Comment: Спасибо, да в общем-то с конкретными знаниями проблем не было...
Вопрос стоял почему разные вещи называются одним словом.
Ну или, чтобы не повторять формулировку "почему" (за я что я сам нередко пеняю, в других, правда, случаях): есть ли скрытая логика в том, что в быту называют совсем не ту часть тела, что в анатомии.